# Bitnami LAMP - Can't connect to localhost

Tags: server, apache2, lamp

ok so I installed Bitnami LAMP. Everything is ok, but i'm unable to access the `phpinfo.php` or any other project I have in the `docs` folder. I get following error:

```
This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost phpinfo
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to fix it?

I can only access phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i figured out that all the project must be under `apache2/htdocs` that's why I was unable to reach my project.

Comment: Please mark your question as accepted.